# d3js bar chart with brush slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js

By looking at the following example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349545, I am trying to replace the circles with a bar chart, representing events per day, for a couple of years worth of data.
Data is the the format

```
 {"15/01/2015: 214","22/03/2016: 30",..}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get bar chart by swapping *data* with new set:

```
var data = [{ "date" : "15/01/2015", "value" : 214}
        ,{ "date" : "22/03/2016", "value" : 30}]
```

parse *date*, change x axis to datetime, and then by change type of *circle* to Rect(with new attributes etc.) in this place:

```
var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d) + "," + y() + ")"; })
.attr("r", 3.5);
```

But, in the example that you brought *brushg* use selectAll on all elements of type Rect, so it will be in the conflict with new approach.